# Confirmation message after redirect in React/Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form, redux-router

I am using `React`, `Redux`, `Redux Router`, and `Redux Form` for a web application, and I would like to implement an "edit" form. The form lives under the URL `/components/1/edit`.

When the form is successfully submitted I would like to redirect to `/components/1` and display a toast with a confirmation message. I can get the redirect to work by hooking into react-form's `props.submitSucceeded` and rendering a `<Redirect/>` tag.

But I am not sure how to propagate the confirmation message so that it is displayed.

Ideally something like the React/Redux take on flash messages in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: In the code block that renders your `<Redirect />` you're going to want to dispatch an action that updates the store. Example: `dispatch({ type: "SHOW_TOAST", message });` You'll want to have a `<Toast />` component that is connected to the store and returns null if it's message prop is empty. When it has a message, it returns the markup of your toast with the message displayed.

Comment: Ok, thank you, that makes sense! Also found this with a bit more information about how to structure the flash messages themselves:  https://alexzywiak.github.io/react-redux-a-flash-messenger-example/index.html

Comment: Glanced at it very briefly, but looks solid at a glance.